# Multiple repos with single submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I've looked for a while and didn't find answer (maybe I don't know what to look).

We've got a main library which is a repository by it self (let's call it Lib) it contains most of our modules and submodules.
Let's also say it has a size of 2GB...

Now we've got many projects such as: ProjA,ProjB,ProjC each one uses the Lib as submodule.

> ProjA
>
> - Lib (branch:master,commit#:1)
>
> ProjB
>
> - Lib (branch:other,commit#:2)
>
> ProjA
>
> - Lib (branch:master,commit#:4)

So while I'm able to keep every project referencing to correct library (aka submodule) version. I've got now 3*2GB = 6GB of THE SAME submodule.

Is there a way to reference to a single submodule while maintaining the correct files/versioning referenced?

Eg.

> ProjA
>
> - Lib/base_lib.h (v1.0)
> - Lib/file_only_in_this_commit
>
> ProjB
>
> - Lib/base_lib.h (v1.0)
>
> ProjC
>
> - Lib/base_lib.h (v1.1)

Thanks!

Comment: Not that I know of. Per repository, you can only have a reference to one SHA in a submodule, hence the reason you added it 3 times. I'm guessing you have this setup because `ProjA`, `ProjB`, and `ProjC` are all related and interact together? Otherwise, this could be 3 different repositories. Or you could have 3 branches in one repository, in which case you'd be able to have different submodule references on each branch with only one version of the submodule

Comment: If your goal is to save space, after initial checkout replace the objects directory with a hardlinked clone

Comment: @basin Is there a way to define such hard links in git? Doing your suggestion manually doesn't really solve the issue, and I would prefer avoiding scripts as well if possible.

Comment: @Danra no. You may try to have one module that refers the real library repo and use relative urls for other two, but I'm not sure this will work

Answer (score 8):

Update:

I've transitioned to using `submodule`'s `--reference` flag and created a new script, [init_submodules](https://github.com/soundradix/git-utils/blob/master/init_submodules.py) to solve the problem using it.

My original/deprecated answer:

You can use `git worktree` (available since git 2.5) to create additional worktrees for the Lib submodule, at the locations inside ProjA, ProjB, etc.

Because `git worktree` makes it a pain to make several worktrees with the same name (all are called "Lib"), I just created a script, [share_submodules](https://github.com/soundradix/git-utils/blob/09f027b6fc240e61bae9917625df615b236ac1de/share_submodules.py) to work around the difficulties and create the additional worktree instead of a submodule, set it to the right submodule commit, and do it recursively for all the submodules inside the shared module.

It should work as well as if the submodule was created by `git submodule update --init --recursive`, except all copies refer to one module's objects.

If you're transitioning to it by removing the submodule, there are stray submodule files in your `.git` and I created [find_stray_submodules.py](https://github.com/soundradix/git-utils/blob/master/find_stray_submodules.py) to clean them up.

Comment: Likely, he/she would need to completely stop using `git submodule`s in this case, wouldn't they?

Comment: @user3159253: this **should** be compatible with `git submodule`. Though I could only say that with high confidence after using this solution for a while (I just started)

Comment: The link share_submodules is 404 not found

Comment: @DrSensor: I've now updated the answer to point to my new script and also fix the link for the old one to point to its last version.

Answer (score 3):

Well, internally the whole submodule thing is quite simple, so you can master it to your taste.

Inside each of your `Proj<N>/.git/modules/` there's a folder corresponding to `Lib` submodule with bare repository cloned from the remote reference specified in `Proj<N>`/.gitmodules in `Lib.url`. Those bare repositories are the points of optimization.

You may simply recreate them using hardlinks where possible.

1) Create a bare clone of your `Lib` in a folder on the same filesystem as your all Proj repos:

```
 git clone --bare url://to/Lib /path/to/Lib.git
```

2) Replace default submodule repo with the repo, referencing the bare repo from p.1:

```
mv ProjA/.git/modules/Lib ProjA/.git/modules/Lib.old // preserve it for a while
git clone --bare --local url://to/Lib \
    --reference /path/to/Lib.git ProjA/.git/modules/Lib
```

3) Restore the config from the preserved repo in `ProjA/.git/modules/Lib`:

```
cp ProjA/.git/modules/Lib.old/config ProjA/.git/modules/Lib/config
```

Now you may check if everything works in `ProjA` and remove `ProjA/.git/modules/Lib.old` and so on. In this case all repos will use the same fileobjects.

In git a particular state of a submodule is referenced by a precise SHA1. Unless you perform some "evil" operations in you `Lib` main repo (e.g. `git filter-branch` or other operations which may lead to deletion of a commit), all proper commits in `Lib` are kept forever. Your `Proj<N>` check out particular commits completely independently of each other, so you shouldn't bother that a state of `Lib` in `ProjA` may interfere with another state of `Lib` in `ProjB`.